# How do I use Pyinspect to get all elements Id in a Win32 app?

Tags: python

I am going to use Pyautowin to automate a Win32 app.

However, I need to know  the control/element names, e.g. all controls or menu items within notepad. I know I can use pyinspect to inspect the elements. However, I don’t seem to get it working. The pyinpect asked me for a .py file, then it just list the methods within the py file. I wonder if I downloaded the right one. Please direct me to the  correct install and it will be even better if there is walkthrough.

Thanks in advance and your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could use the inbuilt inspect.exe within windows :) It works wonders in identifying controllers, element/table names which you can then manipulate with PyAutowin.

More information could be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/inspect-objects